# Can I install a new version of python using only poetry?

Tags: python, python-poetry

### Disclaimer

I'm new to `poetry` and I've searched around, but apologies if I've missed something obvious..

## What I want to do is:

1. specify an arbitrary python version in a poetry project (I don't care how I specify it, but presumably in `pyproject.toml`)
2. run a command (presumably `poetry shell` or `poetry install`, maybe in conjunction with `poetry env use`) that puts me into an environment that uses the python version I specified above (I don't mind if it's a few commands instead of just one)

## I've already tried:

- `poetry env use 3.10` (when I don't have python 3.10 installed already)

  - This gives me an error: `/bin/sh: python3.10: command not found`
  - Notably, I get why this error is showing up, I'd just like to have `poetry` install python 3.10 in this case
- `poetry env use 3.10` (when I'm in a `conda` env that has python 3.10 installed)

  - This works! But... the `python` executeable is symlinked to the one in the conda env
  - Maybe this is fine, but my goal is to use `poetry` instead of `conda` so I'd like to avoid relying on `conda` to install python versions

## What I've seen people do is:

Use `poetry` in conjunction with `pyenv` (where `pyenv` is used to install the python version).

## So, my question is:

Is using something like `pyenv` to install python versions necessary? Is there no way to tell `poetry` that I want *it* to install a given python version?

I've looked through the `poetry` docs, their GH issues, and some SO posts, but (again) apologies if I'm missing something.

## Additional Info

- `poetry` version: 1.1.13
- OS: MacOS (Catalina)
- python version used to install `poetry` (and therefore the one it seems to default to): 3.7.6
- happy to add anything else relevant :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poetry cannot and will not install any python interpreter for you. This is out of scope. It's the responsibility of the user to provide one.

`pyenv` is one way of doing it.